# Update duplicate values of an array of objects in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array like

```
const arr = [
{id: '1', name: 'name 1', age: 20},
{id: '2', name: 'name 2', age: 21},
{id: '2', name: 'name 3', age: 22},
{id: '2', name: 'name 4', age: 23},
{id: '3', name: 'name 5', age: 24},
{id: '3', name: 'name 6', age: 25},
{id: '4', name: 'name 7', age: 26},
{id: '5', name: 'name 8', age: 27},
{id: '5', name: 'name 9', age: 28},
{id: '5', name: 'name 10', age: 29},
];
```

I know I have duplicates(looking only id property) in the array and I don't want to remove duplicates instead, I need to append something to differentiate like.

```
arr = [
{id: '1_0', name: 'name 1', age: 20},
{id: '2_0', name: 'name 2', age: 21},
{id: '2_1', name: 'name 3', age: 22},
{id: '2_2', name: 'name 4', age: 23},
{id: '3_0', name: 'name 5', age: 24},
{id: '3_1', name: 'name 6', age: 25},
{id: '4_0', name: 'name 7', age: 26},
{id: '5_0', name: 'name 8', age: 27},
{id: '5_1', name: 'name 9', age: 28},
{id: '5_2', name: 'name 10', age: 29},
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `2_1` is just `21`, no need for underscores

Comment: @MrMythical what is `210` then? Is it ID 21, instance zero, or is it ID 2 ,instance ten?

Comment: @VLAZ well JavaScript pretty much ignores the underscore. It would be better to use strings for this

Comment: @MrMythical OK, I missed that the ID wasn't a string. I assume OP did mean to use strings, though, given the phrasing for "append". (also, IDs shouldn't be given to consumers as numbers but that's a separate gripe of mine).

Comment: sorry, the property 'id' value should be a string updated the question

Comment: You do realize of course that `id` literally has no meaning any longer. By disassociating the original `id` you no longer have a traceable origin. Might not make a difference now, but it likely will down the road. You should consider using a different data structure.

Comment: Is the array always going to be sorted?

Answer (score 4):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "1", name: "name 1", age: 20 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 2", age: 21 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 3", age: 22 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 4", age: 23 },
  { id: "3", name: "name 5", age: 24 },
  { id: "3", name: "name 6", age: 25 },
  { id: "4", name: "name 7", age: 26 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 8", age: 27 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 9", age: 28 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 10", age: 29 },
];

const map = new Map();
arr.forEach((o) => map.has(o.id) ? map.get(o.id).push(o) : map.set(o.id, [o]));

const result = [];
for (let [, arr] of map) {
  arr.forEach((o, i) => result.push({ ...o, id: `${o.id}_${i}` }));
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**2)** You can also use here [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (Thank to `VLAZ`)

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "1", name: "name 1", age: 20 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 2", age: 21 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 3", age: 22 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 4", age: 23 },
  { id: "3", name: "name 5", age: 24 },
  { id: "3", name: "name 6", age: 25 },
  { id: "4", name: "name 7", age: 26 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 8", age: 27 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 9", age: 28 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 10", age: 29 },
];

const map = new Map();
const result = arr.map((curr) => {
  map.set(curr.id, (map.get(curr.id) ?? -1) + 1);
  return { ...curr, id: `${curr.id}_${map.get(curr.id)}` };
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could take an object for counting and map new objects with subversions.

This answer features a closure

```
(ids => o => ({ ...o, id: `${o.id}_${ids[o.id] ??= 0, ids[o.id]++}` }))
({})
```

where the function is called with an object and returns another function

```
        o => ({ ...o, id: `${o.id}_${ids[o.id] ??= 0, ids[o.id]++}` })
```

for mapping.

The mapping function returns a new object with a replacement of `id` property with part of the old `id` and a new value which starts with zero for any unseen `id`.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: '1', name: 'name 1', age: 20 }, { id: '2', name: 'name 2', age: 21 }, { id: '2', name: 'name 3', age: 22 }, { id: '2', name: 'name 4', age: 23 }, { id: '3', name: 'name 5', age: 24 }, { id: '3', name: 'name 6', age: 25 }, { id: '4', name: 'name 7', age: 26 }, { id: '5', name: 'name 8', age: 27 }, { id: '5', name: 'name 9', age: 28 }, { id: '5', name: 'name 10', age: 29 }],
    result = array.map(
        (ids => o => ({ ...o, id: `${o.id}_${ids[o.id] ??= 0, ids[o.id]++}` }))
        ({})
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; }
```

Comment: @JeremyThille it's the same as the map-counter solution like mine. But Nina uses an object instead and a curried IIFE do keep the counter-object local. Verty simplified this turns code like this `x = 0; fn = num => x += num;` (an outer variable and a function that uses it) into `fn = (x => num => x += num)(0)` (single curried IIFE with `x` passed as an argument leaving just the `num => x += num` part as `fn`).

Comment: Ha, very instructive, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Single iteration needed:

```js
const arr = [
  {id: '1', name: 'name 1', age: 20},
  {id: '2', name: 'name 2', age: 21},
  {id: '2', name: 'name 3', age: 22},
  {id: '2', name: 'name 4', age: 23},
  {id: '3', name: 'name 5', age: 24},
  {id: '3', name: 'name 6', age: 25},
  {id: '4', name: 'name 7', age: 26},
  {id: '5', name: 'name 8', age: 27},
  {id: '5', name: 'name 9', age: 28},
  {id: '5', name: 'name 10', age: 29},
];

//keep track of how many times each id has been encountered
const counterPerRecord = new Map();

for (const record of arr) {
  //get count or default to zero
  const next = counterPerRecord.get(record.id) ?? 0;
  //update the count for next time we encounter the id
  counterPerRecord.set(record.id, next+1);
  
  //update the id
  record.id += `_${next}`;
}

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; }
```

You only need a map to keep track of what the *next* instance for the next number to append to each `id` property. The first time it is zero, and it is increased every time you encounter the same `id`.

Comment: That's a clean and minimal solution. ✅. My second solution is inspired by yours.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "1", name: "name 1", age: 20 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 2", age: 21 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 3", age: 22 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 4", age: 23 },
  { id: "3", name: "name 5", age: 24 },
  { id: "3", name: "name 6", age: 25 },
  { id: "4", name: "name 7", age: 26 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 8", age: 27 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 9", age: 28 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 10", age: 29 },
];

let obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (obj[arr[i].id] == undefined) {
    obj[arr[i].id] = 0;
  } else {
    obj[arr[i].id] = obj[arr[i].id] + 1;
  }
  arr[i].id = arr[i].id + "_" + obj[arr[i].id];
}
console.log(arr);
```

This will do

Answer (score 0):

You can use somthing like this:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "1", name: "name 1", age: 20 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 2", age: 21 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 3", age: 22 },
  { id: "2", name: "name 4", age: 23 },
  { id: "3", name: "name 5", age: 24 },
  { id: "3", name: "name 6", age: 25 },
  { id: "4", name: "name 7", age: 26 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 8", age: 27 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 9", age: 28 },
  { id: "5", name: "name 10", age: 29 },
];

for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   arr[i].id = `${arr[i].id}_${arr.filter(el => el.id === arr[i].id).length - 1}`;
}

console.log(arr);
```

**Notice:** as @MrMythical mentioned, `1_0` is just `10`, `1_1` is `11` and so on. So  I transform ids into strings in example to avoid id duplications.

**Warning:** as @VLAZ and @Jeremy Thille noticed, this is expensive solution  (`O(n^2)`) which is not acceptable for large data. For well-optimized solution (`O(n)`), use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: This solution has `O(n^2)` complexity, since for each item in the array it again traverses the entire array to get the count.

Comment: I agree; it works, looks nice, compact and easy to read, but filtering the whole array for each item in the array is a N² cost. Other solutions here do it at cost N.